# git:// urls with gitolite

Tags: git, gitolite

I am running a gitolite system and I currently clone like this:

```
git clone gitolite@debainserver.local:my-project
```

and it works fine, but I want to clone into an application that needs (no work arounds, tried them all) a git:// address. so how can I set this up.

To clarify a little more look at github's addresses yourself.

```
git clone git://github.com/git/git.git
```

how does this work, and how can I set it up? I want to be able to go

```
git clone git://debainserver.local:my-project
```

and have it clone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to setup `git daemon` appropriately to do that: http://computercamp-cdwilson-us.tumblr.com/post/48589656281/git-gitolite-git-daemon-gitweb-setup-on-ubunt