# Using go language with gitolite

Tags: git, github, go, gitolite

Does know how to use Google's go languages clever get command with Gitolite?
It works great with Google Code and Github as follows:

> go get code.google.com/p/go.example/hello

or

> go get github.com/alphazero/Go-Redis

But my gitolite access look more like:

> git clone git@mygitolite:myproject

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your gitolite server also serving over http(s)? I haven't used go previously, but it seems likely that `go get` uses http(s), not ssh. Assuming you can `git clone http(s)://mygitolite/myproject`, you should be able to `go get mygitolite/myproject`.

Comment: I'm not really sure how it connects. If I explicitly put https:// or ssh:// it fails. It seems to require git clone git@myserver:myproject. Do you know where I can find more on this?

Comment: @cjc343: you may have indirectly answered my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543651/git-urls-with-gitolite?rq=1 describes gitolite a scenarion similar to mine, where gitolite seems to be running with no git or http(s) server.
Next step is to install a git daemon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with gitolite.
Gitolite is just an **[authorization layer](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html)**, which will accept or deny your `git clone/push/pull` command, depending on your username.

If you can declare  a git repo as a source for go, you can use it.
Gitolite will just check who you are, but won't otherwise affect how that repo is used with go.

---

The [OP Peter Krnjevic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155002/peter-krnjevic) [refines the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636150/using-go-language-with-gitolite/14636225#comment20449129_14636225):

> The thing with go, is that it pulls the repo name from the directory structure, so for instance:

```
~/gocode/src/github.com/me/myproject
```

> is automagically transformed into

```
git clone github.com/me/myproject.
```

> **But how can gitolite names be transformed into a path?**

I don't think you need to transform anything: if go is able to contact your git repo (GitHub or any other hosting repo server), gitolite will intercept the command and validate it (or deny it).
You can plug gitolite on top of ssh or (as it is the case with git request done by go import) with https.

But the main point is:

- gitolite is on the server side
- you should use it with an Apache sever (like, for instance, [with my config](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/passenger/apache/env.conf.tpl#L49-L93)), and not ssh, if you want to easily have your repos accessed with go imports.

Comment: Your comment re authorization makes sense: gitolite seems to verify my user name, and I suspect I have a key, though I don't recall for sure.

Comment: The thing with go, is that it pulls the repo name from the directory structure, so for instance:
~/gocode/src/github.com/me/myproject is automagically transformed into git clone https://github.com/me/myproject.
But how can gitolite names be tranformed into a path?

Comment: I upped your answer, as this is useful information, but so far this solve the problem.

Comment: @PeterKrnjevic I have added a link detailing the authorization layer part, and have address your comments in my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a tool just for this use-case. See if it helps.

https://github.com/tuxychandru/gorepos

Comment: Looks interesting. +1 My answer is a more general one.

Comment: VonC's answer to add a webserver (though I think a git daemon should work too) is more generally useful.
However, I will actually use Chandru's solution, due to issues with my git server. I wish I could select two answers! Thanks everyone.